# Java Regex X{n,m} X, at least n but not more than m times

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to understand how to match an email address to the following pattern:

```
      myEmail@something.any
```

The any should be between 2,4 characters.

Please find Java code below. I cannot understand why it returns true. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String a = "daniel@gmail.com";
        String b = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";
        String c = "MyNameis1@abcx.comfff";
        Boolean b1 = c.matches(b);
        System.out.println(b1);
    }
```

OUTPUT: true

Comment: I guess this problem has been solved by other people. If you are stuck, google for the solution, and make sure you understand it.

Comment: Your regex only checks that there are at least 2 to 4 characters after the last dot. It does not state, that there should not be anymore characters. You need to define the [a-zA-Z]{2,4} to be the end of your current line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex, `.` matches any character (except newline). If you want to match `.` literally, you need to escape it:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

This is better, but it still matches the `MyNameis1@abcx.comf` portion. We can add an end of string anchor (`$`) to ensure there are no trailing unmatched characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: You don't need `$` at the end. Java `String.matches` anchors on both ends by default.

Comment: @nhahtdh Nice, didn't know about that. I'd rather keep it for consistency, though.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `.` in `String b = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";`. It is a special character in regex.

Use :  `String b = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}";`

Answer (score 0):

In your expression dot meant any character. escape that and make sure no character follows post your min/max char checks like below:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```